# Tortiose SVN Windows Server 2008 R2 Context Menu

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, contextmenu, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to install TortoiseSVN on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have tried the 32bit versions of Tortoise versions 1.6.16 and 1.5.15. I have used two different admin accounts including the local administrator. The problem is tortoise will not display in the context menu. Any suggestion would be much appreciated because I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: I take it that you are definitely running a 32Bit OS?

Comment: I was told it was a 32bit server (actually a laptop in a backroom) but I just checked and it says 64bit so I'm trying the 64bit installers right now. Although I can't see that should make a difference.

Comment: 64bit Installer Solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment...

Make sure the machine is truely 32bit and not a 64bit OS